# Angularjs: How to populate two different lists in two divs (row wise) alternatively in two different lines on a template?

Tags: angularjs

I have two different lists (each coming from a different API). How to populate that data in two divs (row wise) alternatively in two different lines on a template in AngularJS?

Please let me know if I am not clear. I am relatively new to this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">api_1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in api_1">
      <th>{{n.id}}</th>
      <td>{{n.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
    <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">api_2</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="n in api_2">
        <th>{{n.id}}</th>
        <td>{{n.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tLehZCkpuo0DL5eLNk8z?p=preview

Comment: Please give it a try at least, share some details what you did and where are you stuck.